# How to handle the ajax pagination in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have counted the total results and designed the pagination links. onclicking i am passsing the number value to php file. how to handle $page variable in ajax response. how to show previous 1 2 ... 100 next links like the pagination functionality. I have tried with the following functionality

```
$page = 1;
$total = 10;
$limit = 20;
$total_pages = ceil($total / $limit); 
if (isset($_GET["page"] )) 
                        {
                            $page  = $_GET["page"]; 
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            $page=1; 
                        };
    <ul class="pagination">
<li class="association_page active">1</li>
<li class="association_page">2</li>
<li class="association_page">3</li>
</ul>

echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
     if ($page > 1) {
        echo "<li class='association_page'><a href='#' class='button'>Previous</a></li>"; 
    }

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    if($page==$i){
        echo "<li class='association_page active'>".$i."</li>";
    } else {
        echo "<li class='association_page' >".$i."</li>";
    }
};  
if($page < $total_pages){
    echo "<li class='association_page'>NEXT</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Onclick i am passing the page number to php file and reponse the results json encoding. How to show

Json Output:

```
{"page":"8","html_content":"<li class=\"14\"></li>"}
```

I have not shared full content

Comment: Please share the JSON result?

Comment: As I understand you need to load page content using ajax. you need to register JavaScript click handlers for your pagination links. The click handler should call Php page using ajax. The response of ajax function should be displayed on page